# Will we ever see full support for nVidia Optimus on Linux?

Tags: nvidia-optimus

I've been trying to wait patiently for a while. I want to use Linux a lot, but I don't want to get slower graphics. I paid extra for my graphics card, so I want to get as much gusto as I can. Thanks! I know there's project Bumblebee, but that's still incredibly slower than Windows.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but you could look into [Primus](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/primus-better-performance-and-less.html) and using the [experimental driver](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/use-nvidia-experimental-drivers-310.html) with Bumblebee to improve performance

Answer (score 2):

It seems that finally nVidia has decided to offer support for Optimus on Linux. The official driver supports hybrid graphics in Linux in their latest driver release ([beta version 319.12](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-319.12-driver.html)). 
Read the full release notes [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-319.12-driver.html).

Sources: [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/nvidia-releases-linux-graphics-drivers.html) ,  [phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTM0NzE) , [nvidia documentation](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/319.12/README/randr14.html)

Comment: Except that... it isn't mentioned in the release notes.

Comment: @gertvdijk thanks for pointing that out. Added news sources, which are more informative

Answer (score 1):

You could ask this question at nvidia.com

I guess they blushed because they have overseen to reconfigure xorg.conf - file
(old mistake) which made trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of bumblebee comes with a new `primus` system with better performance than `optirun`:

http://raw.github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/master/doc/RELEASE_NOTES_3_1

There are still issues to work out, like what David Airlie calls "reverse optimus" to make HDMI and other video outputs work straight from the nVidia card:
http://airlied.livejournal.com/76723.html

Please join [this team](https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux) if you are new by clicking on the "Join Team"
link at the right of the Launchpad page. It's important to have as
many users in the community as possible to request for appropriate
support, even if you found a non-obvious way to make it work for you.